# Uploading Google Form Attachments to Specific Google Drive Subfolder

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using this code snippet that I found online.

The google form has 2 portions. First is the name of destination subfolder. Second are the attachments.

But one problem is that every time I submit a response, it creates a duplicate subfolder of the same name.

```
function addFilesToDrive(e) {
  var answers = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var drive = DriveApp;
  var mainFolder = drive.getFolderById('Enter Folder ID here');
  var folderName = answers[0].getResponse();
  var folder = mainFolder.createFolder(folderName);
  var attachments = answers[1].getResponse();
  for (var file in attachments){
    var attachment = drive.getFileById(attachments[file]);
    folder.addFile(attachment);
  }
}
```

How to make it so that the files I upload are uploaded to the same subfolder without duplication?

[Google Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTrtp.png)

[Duplicate Folder problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emGwt.png)

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a folder with the same name exists this way:

```
function addFilesToDrive(e) {
  var answers = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var drive = DriveApp;
  var mainFolder = drive.getFolderById('Enter Folder ID here');
  var folderName = answers[0].getResponse();
 
  try {
    var folder = mainFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  } catch (e) {
    var folder = mainFolder.createFolder(folderName);
  }

  var attachments = answers[1].getResponse();
  for (var file in attachments) {
    var attachment = drive.getFileById(attachments[file]);
    folder.addFile(attachment);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Move Folder

```
function movefolder() {
  const f4 = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");
  const f2 = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");
  f4.moveTo(f2);
}
```

[moveTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#moveTo(Folder))